# Sequelize findAndCountAll with substring and distinct with multiple column

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to do a findAndCountAll operation in sequelize. The count will be based on a combination of 3 distinct columns. One of the column has a substring operation (resource column)

My **Client** Table is as follows,

```
id, clientId, accountId, resource
1,  4f16,     2b18,      table::res/123
2,  4f16,     2b18,      chair::res/123
```

So, I am counting rows based on **clientId, accountId**, **resourceId**(string after **res/** on resource column). So, with above entries I should get **1** as count since **clientId, accountId and resourceId** is same for both the columns.

My plain postgres query is

> select distinct c."accountId", c."clientId", substring("resource" from
>   'res/([^$]+)') as "resourceId"
>         from "Client" as c

My sequelize query now looks like following where there's no **distinct**,

```
 const { rows, count} = await this.client.findAndCountAll({
  where: {
     clientId: clientId!
  },
  attributes: ['clientId', 'accountId',
    [fn('SUBSTRING', '"resource" from res/([^$]+)'), 'resId'],
    [fn('COUNT', col('id')), 'totalResource']],
  group: ['clientId', 'accountId', 'resource'],
   raw: true
});
```

I am not sure how to do that substring part and also do the distinct on 3 columns. With my above query I getting **"SequelizeDatabaseError: function pg_catalog.substring(unknown) does not exist**

Answer (score 0):

Was able to make it work with following code:

```
 const { rows, count} = await this.client.findAndCountAll({
      where: {
         clientId: clientId!
      },
      attributes: [
        fn('DISTINCT', col('clientId'), col('accountId'),  [fn('substring', col('resource') , 'res/([^$]+)'), 'resId']) ],
      group: ['clientId', 'accountId', 'resId'],
       raw: true
    });
```